# Creating a GWTclient with Clojure on the server in Eclipse

Tags: gwt, clojure

I would like to make a website using GWT, so I can use the java-to-javascript compiler for the client side. However, I would like to make a service that my client can call using the default RPC-mechanism of GWT, in Clojure instead of Java. 
I don't know anything about Maven. I use Eclipse to generate and develop the GWT project. How do I set this up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use GWT-RPC mechanism, you create three java files: two interfaces YourService.java and YourServiceAsync.java, and server-side implementation YourServiceImpl.java

Then you create Clojure code with business-logic, link it as library to the main GWT project.

Your implementation file will receive requests from client and call clojure for implementation.

I'd like to realize such approach too.